# How to refactor code inside the componentWillMount event?

Tags: reactjs

I am refactoring my reactjs (react v16.0.0) component and trying to change the name of the componentWillMount event to componentDidMount because of deprecation. Here is the original code:

```
componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({
        myVar: this.getValue(),
      });
    }
}
```

When I change this to componentDidMount I get an eslint error:

```
Do not use setState in componentDidMount
```

How can I get around this? How to fix this eslint error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try set state not directly on the `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.onMount(this.getValue());
}

onMount(newValue){
    this.setState({
        myVar: newValue
    });
}
```

Also you could disable your `eslint` plugin